# Using the % command on a line without a bracket

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions

I like formating code this way:

```
class A
{
}
```

unlike another common way:

```
class B {
}
```

The thing is, when using the `%` command to go to the enclosing bracket, which is very useful for copying/deleting loops/functions, it doesn't work so well on the first case - it just doesn't work if my cursor is on the line without the brackets.

Does anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 5):

I tried to figure if Vim had some option for this and I believe it doesn't. So I wrote a Vim script to do the job. Just add it to your `.vimrc`.

```
function Percent_nextline()
    let line = getline('.')
    if line =~ "{"
        normal! %
    else
        let line = getline(line('.')+1)
        if line =~ "{"
            normal! j%
        endif
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap g% :<C-u>call Percent_nextline()<cr>
onoremap g% :<C-u>execute 'normal! V'<Bar>call Percent_nextline()<cr>
```

This script maps the behaviour you want to `g%`. With the cursor on the line `class A` you can type `g%` and the cursor will jump to the closing curly bracket. It can be preceded with commands like `c`, `d` and `y`.

I implemented this by simply checking if the current line contains a `{`. If it does then the command behaves as `%`. If it doesn't the following line is checked and if a `{` is found the `%` command is called upon that line. The `onoremap` makes it possible to use the mapping in *operator-pending mode*, which is used by `c`, `d` and `y`.

I am sure this script could be improved. It is my first :)

<sub>I want to thank @IngoKarkat for helping me in [How to make a movement function work with delete, yank, etc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/how-to-make-a-movement-function-work-with-delete-yank-etc/).</sub>

Comment: You should add the case for when you are on `}` to keep the muscle memory the same.

Answer (score 0):

With the [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) plugin, it is very easy to define your own motions.

You didn't mention which language you're using, but a naive example for C++ might be something like:

```
call textobj#user#plugin('cpp', {
    \   'code': {
        \     'pattern': ['^class .*\n{', '^}'],
        \     'select-a': 'ac',
        \     'select-i': 'ic',
    \ },
\})
```

You can use `vac` to select "A class", or `vic` to select the inner class; or `dic` to delete the entire inner class, `yic` to yank it, etc.