# How to make a movement function work with delete, yank, etc

Tags: cursor-movement, vimscript

In hope of answering
[Using the % command on a line without a bracket](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/using-the-command-on-a-line-without-a-bracket)
I tried to write my first Vim script.

My thought was to check if there was a `{` on the current line. If there was one I wanted `%` to behave as usual. If not `%` would be called on the next line by doing `j%`. This is what I wrote

```
function Percent_nextline()
    let line = getline('.')
    if line =~ "{"
        normal %
    else
        normal j%
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap g% :call Percent_nextline()<cr>
```

Then I tried it on this file

```
foo
{
    { }
}
```

With the cursor on the first line typing `g%` does indeed move the cursor to the last `}`. Then I tried `dg%`, meaning to delete all the block. This failed, and made the bell sound. The buffer was left unchanged.

So I have two questions:

- How could I make commands like `c`, `y`, `d`, etc. work with this new mapping?
- If I want to use just `%` rather than `g%` how could I stop the function from recursing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*how could I make commands like c, y, d, etc. work with this new mapping?*

In Vim, it's all in the *modes*. The one after commands like `c`, `y`, etc., where Vim is waiting for the `{motion}`, is called *operator-pending mode*. `:help omap-info` explains that you can visually select the block to work upon. Likewise, you probably want to define a visual-mode mapping, too:

```
:nnoremap % :<C-u>call Percent_nextline()<cr>
:xnoremap % :<C-u>execute 'normal! gv'<Bar>call Percent_nextline()<cr>
:onoremap % :<C-u>execute 'normal! V'<Bar>call Percent_nextline()<cr>
```

- the `<C-u>` removes the range inserted in visual mode (and if you use a `[count]`)
- the visual mode mapping first re-creates the existing selection with `gv`
- likewise, the `:omap` goes into line-wise (I think this makes the most sense here) selection

*if I want to use just % rather than g% how could I stop the function from recursing?*

By using `:normal!` (with `!`), existing mappings are ignored. Like `:noremap`, you should always use this, unless you explicitly need mappings to apply. Here, you only lose the functionality of the *matchit* plugin (in case you have that installed), but for pure `{`...`}` matching, you don't need that. You might consider sticking to the `g%` alternative mapping (or using a filetype-specific `:map <buffer> %` only for C/C++).

#### Open issues

- When there's no matching `{`...`}`, your mappings go one line down, which I find irritating. I think you can fix that easily yourself.
- Drop the `:` sigil; in a script, this isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. With your answer I learned about `normal!`, `onoremap` and that the `:` is not needed in the script. I will edit my question and remove the `:`s. You can read my asnwer on http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2823/356. Feel free to edit it if you think it can be improved.