# Is there any point in using C-u in an nmap?

Tags: key-bindings

When creating visual mode maps, you prefix ex commands with `<C-u>` to clear out the range if it's unused:

```
:xnoremap % :<C-u>execute 'normal! gv'<Bar>call Percent_nextline()<cr>
```

(example from [How to make a movement function work with delete, yank, etc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/how-to-make-a-movement-function-work-with-delete-yank-etc/2821#2821))

But is there any point in doing so for normal maps? I can't imagine any scenario where a normal noremap ends up with text in the cmdline.

In summary, do I ever need this:

```
:nnoremap % :<C-u>call Percent_nextline()<cr>
```

over this:

```
:nnoremap % :call Percent_nextline()<cr>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of `<C-u>` is to make the macro not bail out when used with a count.  If you press, say, <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> in normal mode you'll get `.,.+2` inserted automatically on the command line.  This seldom makes sense for the map being defined.  Of course this is more useful if your macro cares about counts (see `:help v:count` for an example), but even if it doesn't, adding `<C-u>` makes the macro tolerant to being called (perhaps inadvertently) with a count.  Pressing <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> is an error with your definition, but works just fine with the original definition.